# Is it possible to use executables having no debug symbols with valgrind?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, valgrind

I have been trying to debug a piece of code using valgrind and gdb.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   int main()
   {
           int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
           free(p);
           return 0;
   }
```

- I have compiled it using command `gcc prog.c -o prog -g`. When I run
  it with gdb and valgrind, it works fine.
- Then I removed the debugging symbols by command `strip --strip-all
  prog`.
- Then I run the same with gdb and valgrind. So gdb shows "no debugging
  information is available" where as in valgrind run successfully and
  shows no such warnings.

Also I tried to check the size using command `size` for both the cases. But I could not find any difference.

**How to find whether debugging information has added? How is it possible to find the leakcheck using valgrind without having debugging symbols along with the executable?**

Comment: Possible yes, but it will not be able to report things like file-names or line-numbers when it detects problems.

Comment: One way to see if an executable have debug information is with the [`file`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok. I could identify whether it is stripped or not using file command.

Comment: how valgring can know when you for example call malloc without debug information? IMO it is not possible

Comment: @P__J__: it can't -- if you statically link your code with a `malloc` implementation. But if you did that, valgrind wouldn't work even with debug information because it works by linking with its own memory management functions. On the other hand, external symbols aren't part of debug information and stripping an executable does not affect linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to find whether debugging information has added?

The easiest way is probably to use the `file` utility.  Example:

```
file my_executable
```

Among the information it provides is whether debug symbols are present or have been stripped.

There are various other tools that can do this, too, among them GNU readelf (for ELF executables).  Debug information will appear in one or more of its own sections of an ELF binary, and you will see those in a list of the sections.

> How is it possible to find the leakcheck using valgrind without having debugging symbols along with the executable?

The same way it is possible to run the program at all without debugging symbols.  Valgrind does not need the debugging information to monitor program behavior.  Its main hook is to provide its own special `malloc()` and `free()` implementations.  Having debug information available just allows it to emit more human-interpretable diagnostic messages, which is, after all, the whole point of debug symbols in the first place.

To a limited extent, you can debug a program with gdb without debugging symbols, too, but it's painful because so much of what you ordinarily want to do with a debugger depends on mapping details of the executable back to the source.  Very little such mapping is possible without the debug symbols.

Comment: John, if it is an executable with no symbol information, how can Valgrind provide its own malloc and free, as there are no known symbols to replace or hook to?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, there are no *debugging* symbols.  All dynamically-linked executables contain the symbols used for dynamic linking, and these are what Valgrind hooks.

Comment: OK, so it works for dynamically linked applications but not for statically linked applications. A simple program would be statically linked I presume? Your comment/answer clarifies a lot.

Comment: @paul: it's pretty uncommon to find a Linux executable statically linked with the standard C library. And if you had one, I don't believe valgrind would be able to substitute its own implementation.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: ok, I checked the valgrind docs. It can intercept malloc calls in a statically-linked executable provided that the library entry points are exported as global symbols. Global symbols are not part of the debugging information, so stripping debug information doesn't affect them.

Comment: @rici, in a statically linked executable there is no need for the library functions (entry points) to be provided as global symbols. It is already linked. All the loader now does is relocate things but it needs no symbols for that. Note though that my reference is dos/windows, not unix/linux.

Comment: @paul: the fact that an executable is statically linked does not mean that all of its entry points disappear. (Otherwise, how would you find `main`?) Statically-linked executables still export global symbols through linkage sections, not debugging information. And, aiui, that's what valgrind uses to find the functions it needs to substitute.

Comment: @rici, `main` is called from the crt startup. crt startup is in a library and is statically linked. The executable file format has an entry that gives the [to be relocated] entry address of the program, that wil be the crt startup main routine. The linker places this address in the exe file header. There is no need for symbols. On this scenario valgrind cannot work. Linux seems to have more intelligent linking/loading.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, speaking only to Linux, as that's how the question is tagged, it is unusual for simple programs built on a modern Linux to be statically linked.  Dynamic linking is the default for every Linux toolchain I know about.  In some cases, the toolchain components needed for building statically linked binaries aren't all even installed by default.  Especially programs built for academic exercises are very likely to be dynamically linked, because you need to explicitly ask for static linking if that's what you want, and few students are even aware of the option.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, just to satisfy my curiosity, would there be a single generic dynamic library on Linux or would each compiler have its own distribution? Although the dynamic linking is more efficient, it could create problems with program distribution and installation if there is no generic library.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, as a practical matter, Linux distributions tend to each standardize on one implementation of the C standard library -- typically Glibc, but it is *not* universal.  Having a per-distribution standard resolves the combinatorial problem.  There is little *technical* problem with having multiple C libraries, as the DSO formats used on Linux carry the information needed to choose the right library binary, and Linux packaging formats provide for dependency identification and resolution.